# How would you find the size of a Binary Search Tree without recursion?

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I know how to find the size of a tree with recursion, but I am unsure on how to find it without recursion. 
Here is what i have so far. I think that it is my if statement that is preventing me from transversing the tree.

```
  public int size() {
    size = 0;
    NodeWord current = root;
    while(current != null) {
        if(current.left != null) {
            size++;
        }
        else {
            current = current.right;
        }
    }
    return size;
}
```

Comment: Could you post your code through editing this question? Please show us what you tried to do.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you wish to transform a recursive solution to an iterative one, you can use a `Stack`.

- In this case you can use a `Stack<Node>`, where `Node` is a `Node` of the binary search tree.
- You start by pushing the root `Node` into the Stack.
- Then you write a while loop that keeps going until the Stack is empty.
- In each iteration of the while loop you can peek at the top `Node` of the `Stack` and push the children of that `Node` into the `Stack`. If it has no children, you pop that `Node` out of the `Stack` and do whatever calculation you need to do with it (just increment a counter in your example).
- You can change the order in which you push and pop the current `Node` and its two children depending on the desired order of traversal of the tree.

Comment: That was really helpful thanks. I had one follow up question regarding Binary Search Trees. What is meant by a Level in a BST. Does one level describe a branch or and entire subtree?